"NFC service not working" continuously pop up on Oukitel WP15
I've had "NFC service not working" continuously pop up on my Oukitel WP15. A couple of months ago, it started doing this.
I went through some of the troubleshooting steps that are listed in this forum, like trying to force-stop the app, and trying to disable it. I tried to clear the cache and all sorts of stuff, but none of it worked, it kept popping back up.
Then I downloaded an antivirus software (I think AVG), then it told me there was a corrupt app, that was an app for CDL testing. I deleted the app, the pop-up appeared again. I cleared the cache and the memory, and then I didn't see it again for 2 months.
Now it's back. I've since done a couple of things like deleted a couple of apps and then reset the phone, and then it went away for like a half day. Then it's back.
I have a lot of apps on my phone and folders. I don't want to have to restart my phone. Also, I don't even know a good app that will redownload all my other apps. I must have 200 to 300 apps on my phone.
What do I do?

Please note that your question in it's original form was just a bunch of unstructured word without any punctuation marks or sentences. Nobody want's to read such a mess, thus your chance getting an answer was next to zero. If you post something is a community please make sure to write a text that is easy to read, otherwise people will ignore it.

Not sure if it's possible on this device or not, but have you tried disabling the NFC from the Android Settings itself?
